# In the MIMIC II database, where can I get the "type of admission", which could be scheduled surgical, unscheduled surgical or medical?

Tags: mimic-iii

In the MIMIC II database can we use the comorbidity_score table to get which patients have AIDs, metastatic cancer and hematologic malignancy (as these three diseases are included in the table as boolean variables - 1 means diseased and 0 means healthy from disease)

Comment: Are you asking two different questions? If so, please just ask one question per page.

Answer (score 1):

The type of admission is recorded in the admissions table:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(admission_type)
FROM admissions;
```

returns:

```
 admission_type 
----------------
 ELECTIVE
 URGENT
 NEWBORN
 EMERGENCY
```